# F# Deedle Filtering a data frame using String.Contains

Tags: string, f#, contains, deedle

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
          Date                        Type   last  LastSize       
12    -> 2013-10-25T00:00:00.575556Z  trade 273  20     
13    -> 2013-10-25T00:00:00.575556Z  quote 0    0       
:         ...                         ...    ...   ...      
26554 -> 2013-10-25T06:04:59.741493Z  trade 273  2       
26555 -> 2013-10-25T06:04:59.751844Z  trade 273  8
```

I want to filter based on the field labelled `Type`. Specifically I want to filter the data frame to only includes rows where the column `Type` **contains** the string "trade".

```
let tradesOnly = lastFrame.GetSeries<string>("Type")
                |> Series.filterValues (fun t -> t.Contains "trade")
```

This will correctly filter but only gives me the series as I am using `GetSeries`. 
The Deedle samples include have a snippet somewhat like this

```
let x = lastFrame.RowsDense 
        |> Series.filterValues (fun row -> row.GetAs<string>("Type") = "trade")
        |> Series.countValues
```

This compiles but return an empty data frame as I need `contains` not `equals`. How can filter a frame by string contains? `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`row.GetAs<string>("Type").Contains("trade")` should do it.